# how to prevent single click event when double clicked in dhtmlx

Tags: events, dhtmlx

I have a gantt attached to onTaskClick and onTaskDblClick events. 
When I double click it also fires the onTaskClick event. 
How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

It can be non-trivial because the fact is that when the first `onTaskClick` event fires there is no way to determine whether a user is done with clicking or is he going to do another single click which will then invoke double click event. So if you capture events in browser double click will always look like a sequence 'click'-'click'-'doubleclick'.

So if you need onclick not to fire for double clicks, you may need some timeout in onclick handler in order to check whether next click/doubleclick follows(200-300ms, the exact value may vary between browsers and OS). That way when the user does a single click, the onclick handler will be executed after some delay, and if it's the double click - a timeout for a click handler will be dropped so only `onTaskDblClick` handler will run.

```
var a;
gantt.attachEvent("onTaskClick", function(id,e){
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (a) {
      return false;
    } else {
      gantt.message("onTaskClick")
      return true;
    }
  }, 200)
  a = 0;
});


gantt.attachEvent("onTaskDblClick", function(id,e){
    gantt.message("onTaskDblClick")
    a=1;
    return true;
});
```

Please check this [snippet](https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/a114dc193) that demonstrates how it works.